# Want flush-left alignment and unnumbered equations, but 'flalign*' doesn't get the job done

Tags: align, amsmath, alignment

I use `flalign` instead of `align` because i need left alignment and not centering. But by default the tag automatically included. How to remove the tag? If i use `\flalign*`, the alignment would change to the center just like when i use `\begin{align}`.

MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % ('amssymb' loads 'amsfonts' automatically)
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*} % remove the tag 
\text{Where: } A &= \text{Apple}\\
B &= \text{Banana}\\
C &= \text{Cherry}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `flalign(*)` creates full length alignment, not left alignment. It acts like lift alignment when you put an empty second group of equations, for example `\text{Where: } A &= Apple & \\`, note the second `&` playing role of separator of groups of equations.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ so what is the alternative? I want left alignment. Like using `\begin{align}` but the alignment is on the left. Not on the center. Thanks

Comment: If you want to left align every equation, use @Mico's answer. If you want to left align specific equation while keeping others centered, use `\begin{flalign} \text{Where: } A &= Apple & \\ ... \end{flalign}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you prefer a local left-flush (as I do), you may need to have a look at the package [nccmath](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/doc/nccmath.pdf) with its environment `fleqn`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{nccmath} % <-- load nccmath
\begin{document}
    \begin{fleqn} % <-- from nccmath package
        \begin{align*}
        \text{Where: } A &= \text{Apple}\\
        B &= \text{Banana}\\
        C &= \text{Cherry}
        \end{align*}
    \end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

The "fl" in `flalign` and `flalign*` stands for "full length", *not* "flush left".

In order to achieve your formatting objective, you should load the `amsmath` package with the option `fleqn`. (Here, "fl" really does mean "flush left".)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} % no equation numbering
\text{Where: } A &= \text{Apple}\\
               B &= \text{Banana}\\
               C &= \text{Cherry}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the `fleqn` package option changes alignment for every `amsmath` display math environment.

Answer (score 7):

You can define your own environment:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{flushleftequation*}
 {\begin{equation*}\begin{lrbox}{\flusheqbox}$\displaystyle}
 {$\end{lrbox}\makebox[\displaywidth][l]{\usebox{\flusheqbox}}\end{equation*}\ignorespacesafterend}
\newsavebox{\flusheqbox}

\begin{document}

Some text before the conditions
\begin{flushleftequation*}
  \begin{aligned}
  \text{Where: } A &= \text{Apple}\\
  B &= \text{Banana}\\
  C &= \text{Cherry}
  \end{aligned}
\end{flushleftequation*}
Some text after the conditions.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you *can* do it with `flalign`, keeping in mind that it stands for “full length align” and not “flush left align”: just add something that will trigger full length.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some text before the conditions
\begin{flalign*}
  \text{Where: } A &= \text{Apple} && \\
  B &= \text{Banana} \\
  C &= \text{Cherry}
\end{flalign*}
Some text after the conditions.

\end{document}
```